# Passing array of stuct to kernel results in segfault on write?

Tags: c++, opencl

Maybe I missed something from the tutorials because this is driving me nuts.

What I'm trying to accomplish: I want to create an *array of structs* for the OpenCL device to use as a work area.  The host doesn't need to see it or interact with it in any way, it's just meant as a "scratch" space for the kernel to work within.

**Here's what I have:**

Declaration of struct inside header file accessible by both the main program and the OpenCL kernel:

```
typedef struct {
    uint64_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} result_list;
```

Initializing the scratch space buffer "outputBuffer" to hold MAX_SIZE elements:

```
      cl_mem outputBuffer;
      outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(this->context,
                                    CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                                    sizeof(result_list) * MAX_SIZE,
                                    NULL,
                                    &status);
```

I never call `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` because the host doesn't care what the memory is.  It's simply meant to be a working space for the kernel.  I leave it as uninitialized but allocated.

Setting it as an argument for the kernel to use:

```
status = clSetKernelArg(myKernel,
                        1,
                        sizeof(cl_mem),
                        &this->outputBuffer);
```

The kernel (simplified to remove non-issue sections):

```
__kernel void kernelFunc(__global const uint32_t *input, __global result_list *outputBuffer) {
    if (get_global_id(0) >= MAX_SIZE) { return; }

    // Make a few local variables and play with them
    outputBuffer[0].a = 1234;  // Memory access violation here
    // Code never reaches here
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

I installed CodeXL from AMD and it doesn't help much with debugging issues like these.  The most it gives me is "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address to which it does not have access."

---

**edit:** It seems like it really doesn't like typedefs.  Instead of using a struct, I simplified it to `typedef uint64_t result_list` and it refused to compile, saying "a value of type 'ulong' cannot be assigned to an entity of type 'result_list'", even though result_list -> uint64_t -> unsigned long.

Comment: I would try first with a simple array of floats to see that everything is working, and then switch to a struct.

Comment: Actually array of uint64_t would make more sense. Get that working first and then switch to a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot put in a single header both definitions for HOST and DEVICE.
You have to separate them like this:

```
//HOST header
struct mystruct{
    cl_ulong a;
    cl_uint b;
};

//DEVICE header
typedef struct{
    ulong a;
    uint b;
} mystruct;
```

Notice that I also changed the datatype to the standar OpenCL datatypes. You should use those instead for compatibility.